# is it possible to filter a section with a specific class?

Tags: html, css

Hello i would like to know if it is possible to filter a section with a specific class ? here is my code

```
<section class="portfolio_masonry" > 
    <div class="row isotope_portfolio_container">
        <div class="new col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="portfolio_item">
                <a href="images/portfolio/lenses.jpg" class="lightbox">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/lenses.jpg" alt="Community & Non-Profit" >
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="desc">
                            <h4>Lenses to Their World</h4>
                            <span class="cross"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the list gose on i need to filter this to not show all images in the start of the section but just specific calss images? thank you in advance

Comment: Please explain further what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "filter"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using `('.div').filter('.yourclass')`

Comment: Neither JavaScript nor jQuery are tagged. I don't see how this will help OP at all.